# ADO.NET Customer Error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I've created an application that works perfectly on my PC using C# and SQL Server 2014.

My connection string is:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Youssef\Desktop\gone\gone\gone\gestion_incidents.mdf;Initial Catalog=BG_ONE;Integrated Security=True
```

I know that the connection string is the problem but how can I create a connection string that works on all computers?

Comment: What do you mean by *"works in every PC"* ?

Comment: i mean works on customer computers not just mine

Comment: Yeah. now give us the details. SqlException has a lot more info than just a number.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your database file path to a generic path that automatically get the location of the project data folder and it will not cause problem when you move project to another location. Follow below steps:

Step 1: First Add `App_Data` folder in your project and add database file there.
Step 2: Change your connection string replace path before the database file with `|DataDirectory|`

Example:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\nwind.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

If you follow the above steps then your connection replace `C:\Users\Youssef\Desktop\gone\gone\gone` with `|DataDirectory|`. See modified connection string as below:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Youssef\Desktop\gone\gone\gone\gestion_incidents.mdf;Initial Catalog=BG_ONE;Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: @AyoubElHafi: Great.. Then always remember to mark provide solution as answer that help to solve your issue.